# Road painting ahead

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art

Given two parameters *lane pattern* and *road length*, print an ASCII representation of the lane markings for Roads and Traffic Service to paint the roads.

### Example input/output

**Input:** `BTHMLRPHU`, 21

I don't care if you take two parameters or concatenate the number onto the end of the string, it's unambiguous.

Input may be taken from STDIN, as a function argument, environment variables, whatever makes sense in your language.

**Output:**

```
!   |      x      ##      |      |      x      x      !
! B |  /\  x HOV3 ##  <-  |  ->  |  ^^  x HOV3 x      !
! B |  \/  x HOV3 ##   |  |  |   |  ^^  x HOV3 x      !
!   |      x      ##      |      |      x      x      !
!   |      x      ##      |      |      x      x      !
!   |      |      ##      |      |      |      |      !
!   |      |      ##      |      |      |      |      !
!   |      |      ##      |      |      |      |      !
! B |  /\  | HOV3 ##  <-  |  ->  |  ^^  | HOV3 |      !
! B |  \/  | HOV3 ##   |  |  |   |  ^^  | HOV3 |      !
!   |      x      ##      |      |      x      x      !
! B |  /\  x HOV3 ##  <-  |  ->  |  ^^  x HOV3 x      !
! B |  \/  x HOV3 ##   |  |  |   |  ^^  x HOV3 x      !
!   |      x      ##      |      |      x      x      !
!   |      x      ##      |      |      x      x      !
!   |      |      ##      |      |      |      |      !
!   |      |      ##      |      |      |      |      !
!   |      |      ##      |      |      |      |      !
! B |  /\  | HOV3 ##  <-  |  ->  |  ^^  | HOV3 |      !
! B |  \/  | HOV3 ##   |  |  |   |  ^^  | HOV3 |      !
!   |      x      ##      |      |      x      x      !
```

Each character denotes 0.5 metres in width and one kilometre in length.

## Specification

### Lane markings

For every 10 km stretch of road, markings are painted at kilometres 2, 3, 9 and 10 (from the "top" of the output). Markings are centred in the lane. With the exception of the bike lane and median, all lanes are 3 metres (6 characters) wide.

ASCII diamond and arrow characters are *not* permitted in lieu of the markings as indicated in the example output.

- `B`: Bike lane. `B` marking. 1.5 metres (3 characters) wide.
- `T`: Transit. Diamond marking
- `H`: High-occupancy vehicle lane. `HOV3` marking
- `L` and `R`: Turning lane. Arrow marking
- `P`: Passing lane. Caret markings
- `U`: Unrestricted lane. No markings

### Separators (in order of precedence)

- Median: `##` (denoted by `M` in the input string, replaces any other separator including ditch)
- Ditch (extreme left and extreme right): `!` Exclamation mark
- HOV lanes alternate between `x` and `|` every 5 km
- Normal: `|`

### Constraints

Your function or program must:

- Print to STDOUT (this means equivalents of `System.out.print` for Java, `console.log` for JavaScript, etc.)
- Be able to print 1 - 9 lanes with 0 - 10 medians
- Be able to print up to 50 km of roadway (50 lines of output)
- [Not use any standard loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1061/22867)
- Trailing white space is not acceptable with the exception of an optional `\n` at the end of the output

Largest possible output: 3700 bytes (74 characters * 50 lines).

Smallest possible output: 5 bytes (with input `B`, 1)

#### Assumptions

- No adjacent medians (substring `MM` will not occur)
- The second line of markings might be cut off (for example if the length is 9 or 12 km)
- Lanes may not logically make sense (any order is possible, for example a right turn lane on the left of the road)

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest code (in bytes) wins!

Comment: And there, you loves monospaced fonts

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Ruby, 245

Print the lane divides if relevant, then print the lane.

I don't expect to win.

```ruby
->(n,i){i.times{|d,t|*e=''
g=e+%w{HOV3 ^^ B}
n.chars{|c|$><<(c==?M?'##':!t ??!:(t+c)[?H]&&d%10<5??x:?|)if(M=t!=?M)
$><<((e+[(%w{/\\ <- ->}+g)[v='TLRUHPB'.index(c)],(%w{\\/ \ | |\ }+g)[v]]+e*4)*2)[d%10].center(v>5?3:6)if(t=c)!=?M}
puts M ? e:?!}}
```

#### Changelog

**245** choke stderr and split arrays effectively.

**263** better way to index array

**268** just print each line, don't calculate a canonical version.

**330** initial commit

Comment: I wouldn't expect Ruby to win either but if there aren't any other answers within the next week then I guess you win :-P On a second note is there anywhere I can test this without installing Ruby on my computer?

Comment: @rink.attendant.6 http://ideone.com/

Answer (score 2):

### JavaScript (ES6), 316 bytes

```js
f=(x,n)=>{for(i=0;n>i++;){b=!(r=i%10)|r==3;y=[...`! ${[...x].join` | `} !`[o='replace'](/[\W] ?M [\W]?/g,'##')].map(c=>~(q='LPRTU'.indexOf(c))?` ${'<- |^^^^->| /\\\\/    '.substr(4*q+2*b,2)} `:c=='H'?'HOV3':c).join``;y=r&&r<6?y[o](/\| H/g,'x H')[o](/3 \|/g,'3 x'):y;console.log(b|r==2|r==9?y:y[o](/[^!\|x#]/g,' '))}}
```

#### Demo

It should work in Firefox and Edge at time of writing, Chrome/Opera require experimental features to be enabled.

```js
console.log = x => O.innerHTML += x + '\n';

f = (x, n) => {
  for (i = 0; n > i++;) {
    b = !(r = i % 10) | r == 3;
    y = [...
      `! ${[...x].join` | `} !` [o = 'replace'](/[\W] ?M [\W]?/g, '##')
    ].map(c => ~(q = 'LPRTU'.indexOf(c)) ? ` ${'<- |^^^^->| /\\\\/    '.substr(4*q+2*b,2)} ` : c == 'H' ? 'HOV3' : c).join ``;
    y = r && r < 6 ? y[o](/\| H/g, 'x H')[o](/3 \|/g, '3 x') : y;
    console.log(b | r == 2 | r == 9 ? y : y[o](/[^!\|x#]/g, ' '))
  }
}

// Snippet stuff
var demo = () => {
  O.innerHTML = '';
  document.forms[0].checkValidity() && f(document.getElementById('P').value, document.getElementById('N').valueAsNumber);
};

document.getElementById('P').addEventListener('change', demo);
document.getElementById('N').addEventListener('change', demo);

demo();
```

```html
<form action='#'>
  <p>
    <label>Lane pattern:
      <input type=text pattern=^M?([BHLPRTU]M?)+$ maxlength=19 required id=P value=MLTPUMHUTBR>
    </label>
  </p>
  <p>
    <label>Kilometres:
      <input type=number id=N min=1 value=21 max=50 step=1 required>
    </label>
  </p>
  <pre><output id=O></output></pre>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), <s>175</s> <s>174</s> 175 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
ðTиDU'|TиX'BŽ5ES©ǝX„\/TbSDVè®ǝ€ºX4×"HOV3"®ǝX'<18SǝX„|-Yè®ǝøJDí'<'>:X'^®ǝ2×'#Tи2×'x5и'|5и«'!Tи)I.•o¤[‹‡•uŽDýSтì€ûŽe1ª904ûª8ª₄Â«ª‡•δ~¬]•2ôDí«Ž
ÿT∍S:ð.ø8ðìÂ‚8:1ðìÂ‚ð:SðT:èεI∍}øJ»
```

Pretty bad approach, but it works and was fun to make. Can definitely be golfed some more, though.

+1 byte as bug-fix for two adjacent `HH` lanes.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//8IaQCztcQtVrgFSEutPRvaauwYdWHp8b8ahhXox@SFKwS9jhFYfWHZ/7qGnNoV0RJoenK3n4hxkrgYQi1G0MLYIhamt0IyHqDu/wcjm8Vt1G3c4qQj0OJGJ0eLq6MtB4EF1hemGHeg2QOLRaXREopump96hhUf6hJdGPGnY@algI5JQe3etyeG/wxabDa4B2Ht59dG@q4aFVlgYmh3cfWmVxaNWjppbDTYdWAxlg5ee21B1aEwtkGB3eArT40Oqje7kO7w951NEbbHV4g97hHRaHNxxec7jpUcMsCytDOPvwBqtgoN@tDq84t9UTqLgW6O5Du///dwrx8PUJCvAI9fDw5TIyAgA)

**Explanation:**

Step 1: Create all possible lanes with size 10:

```python
ðTи               # Push a space character, repeated 10 times as list
   DU             # And store a copy in variable `X`
'|Tи             '# Push "|", repeated 10 times as list
X                 # Push the list of spaces of variable `X`
 'B              '# Push a "B"
   Ž5E            # Push compressed integer 1289
      S           # Converted to a list of digits: [1,2,8,9]
       ©          # Store it in variable `®` (without popping)
        ǝ         # Replace the spaces in the pushed `X` with the "B" at these (0-based)
                  # indices
X                 # Push `X` again
 „\/              # Push string "\/"
    TbS           # Push 10, converted to binary, as list: [1,0,1,0]
       DV         # Store a copy in variable `Y`
         è        # Index each into this string: ["/","\","/","\"]
          ®       # Push list `®` again ([1,2,8,9])
           ǝ      # And replace the spaces with these characters
            €º    # And then mirror each line (" "→"  "; "/"→"/\"; "\"→"\/")
X                 # Push `X` again
 4×               # Extend each space to four spaces
   "HOV3"         # Push string "HOV3"
         ®ǝ       # And replace the spaces with this string at the indices of `®` again
X                 # Push `X` again
 '<              '# Push string "<"
   18S            # Push 18 as list: [1,8]
      ǝ           # Replace the spaces with "<" at those indices
       X          # Push `X` yet again
        „-|       # Push string "-|"
           Yè     # Use list `Y` ([1,0,1,0]) to index into this string: ["-","|","-","|"]
             ®ǝ   # And replace the spaces at the indices of `®` again
               ø  # Then zip-pair the two lists together
                J # And join each pair of characters to a string
Dí                # Create a copy and reverse each string
  '<'>:           # And replace all "<" with ">"
X'^®ǝ            '# Push `X` with the spaces at indices `®` replaced with "^" 
     2×           # Extend each character to size 2
'#Tи             '# Push "#", repeated 10 times as list
    2×            # And extend each character to size 2
'x5и             '# Push "x" repeated 5 times as list
    '|5и         '# Push "|" repeated 5 times as list
        «         # And merge the lists together
'!Tи             '# Push "!", repeated 10 times as list
)                 # And finally wrap all lists of the stack into one big list of lanes
```

Step 2: Convert the input-string to indices (which we're going to use to index into the list we created in step 1):

```python
I                 # Push the input-string
 .•o¤[‹‡•         # Push compressed string "tlrpbhmu"
         u        # And uppercase it
ŽDý               # Push compressed integer 3567
   S              # Converted to a list of digits: [3,5,6,7]
    тì            # Prepend each with "100": ["1003","1005","1006","1007"]
      €û          # And palindromize each: ["1003001","1005001","1006001","1007001"]
Že1               # Push compressed integer 10201
   ª              # And append it to the list
904ûª             # Push 904 palindromized to "90409", and also append it to the list
8ª                # Append 8 to the list
₄Â                # Push 1000, and bifurcate it (short for Duplicate & Reverse copy)
  «               # Merge them together: "10000001"
   ª              # And also append it to the list
‡                 # Now transliterate all uppercase characters in the input to these numbers
•δ~¬]•            # Push compressed integer 1119188999
      2ô          # Split into parts of size 2: [11,19,18,89,99]
        Dí        # Create a copy, and reverse each item: [11,91,81,98,99]
          «       # And merge the lists together: [11,19,18,89,99,11,91,81,98,99]
Ž\nÿ              # Push compressed integer 19889
    T∍            # Extended to size 10: 1988919889
      S           # As a list of digits: [1,9,8,8,9,1,9,8,8,9]
:                 # Replace all [11,19,18,89,99,11,91,81,98,99] with [1,9,8,8,9,1,9,8,8,9]
                  # in the converted string
ð.ø               # Surround the string with spaces
8ðì               # Push 8 with a prepended space: " 8"
   Â‚             # Bifurcate and pair: [" 8","8 "]
     8:           # And replace all those for 8 in the string
1ðìÂ‚ð:           # Do the same for [" 1","1 "] → " "
S                 # Convert the string to a list of characters (digits and space)
 ðT:              # Replace the spaces for 10
```

Step 3: we use those indices to index into the list of lanes. And then we convert those list of lanes to the correct output, including extending/shortening them to the size of the integer-input:

```python
è                 # Index the indices in the integer-list into the lanes-list
 ε                # Map over each lane
  I               #  Push the second integer-input
   ∍              #  Extend/shorten each 10-sized lane to this input-size
 }ø               # After the map: zip/transpose; swapping rows/columns
   J              # Join inner list together to a single string
    »             # And then join each string by newlines
                  # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```

[See this 05AB1E tip of mine (sections *How to compress strings not part of the dictionary?* and *How to compress large integers?*)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/166851/52210) to understand why `Ž5E` is `1289`; `.•o¤[‹‡•` is `"tlrpbhmu"`; `ŽDý` is `10201`; `•δ~¬]•` is `1119188999`; `Ž\nÿ` is `19889`.